# How not to block UI interaction simultaneously with intensive task on the main thread

Tags: ios

I have several child controllers. One of them is out of visible frame.

When I should update UI in invisible controller it uses 100% of CPU for a few seconds that blocks UI interaction in visible controller (gestures don't work).

Unfortunately I can't update UI not on the main thread.
Is there any opportunity not to block UI in my case?

Comment: If updating the UI takes "a few seconds" something is most definitely wrong.  Can you post the code causing the lock of the main thread?

Comment: Definitely need code to look at. Whatever is blocking in the thread could still be broken up and worked on in a different thread with only exactly what needs to be called on the UI thread. It's usually safe to do things like UI element creation on a background thread (look at dispatch queues too) and only when you are updating the view hierarchy do you have to run that on the main thread.

Comment: @Byron About UI updates: there are tons of legacy code from real app, so I can't post it. But all this code is connected with UI updates. I'll try to follow your advice and to move UI elements creation on a background thread. Thank you.

Comment: @IgorKorolev you might still be able to wrap that legacy code in async dispatch and call back from the legacy code with another async on main thread. Mostly the only time you absolutely need to call on main thread is when you are "touching" elements or add/removing elements that are already part of the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used NSOperationQueue to break the code into blocks. CPU is still used by 100% (Iphone 4s), but UI is not blocked.

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
queue.qualityOfService = NSQualityOfServiceUserInteractive;
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;

[queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    ...some UI Updates
}];
[queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    ...some UI Updates
}];
[queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    ...some UI Updates
}];
```